# How can i add custom data to 'say something about this..' while using facebook share?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to share a link from my web applicatoin to facebook feed using "**https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=< my-sharing-link >**" along with some content in "**say something about this..**" section.
Is there any way to add some custom content to "**to say something about this..**" section?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this sharing link with a popup using javascript.

```
<a id="shareFB" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLENCODED_URL&t=TITLE" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;"   target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook">
    Share on Facebook
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("shareFB").setAttribute("href", "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + document.URL);</script>
```

Comment: this solution doesnt seems to work.
the part **u=URLENCODED_URL** works but **t=TITLE** doesnt work

the new window is opening with the **URLENCODED_URL** but **TITLE** is missing